# Custom checkbox with hidden inputs not selecting properly. Javascript needs adjusting

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I am using custom checkboxes with the `input` hidden wrapped in a `span`; I have written a script to add the class for `checked`, but it doesn't actually mark the inputs as checked.  What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:  So the checkbox checks now!  Hooray.  A new problem is that hiding the visibility on the checkbox, also hides the new class when checked on the area of the checkbox... if the label is clicked, then the checkbox shows as checked, but if the checkbox image itself is clicked, nothing changes...**

HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <label class="sublabel" title="Insights & Planning" for="checkbox-insights-and-planning">Insights & Planning</label>

  <span class="open-checkbox">
     <input id="checkbox-insights-and-planning" class="key-areas-checkbox" name="key-areas-of-interest" type="checkbox" />
  </span>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.open-checkbox {
    background-position: -4px -48px;
    background-image: url(../images/adcolor-sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 25px;
}

.checked {
    background-position: -4px -12px;
    background-image: url(../images/adcolor-sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 25px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#key-areas-inputs label.sublabel {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
#key-areas-inputs input.key-areas-checkbox {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    clear: none;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#key-areas-label {
    font-family: "Futura W01 Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #df007c;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 348px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

JS

```
// check checked boxes on load     
    $(".key-areas-checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).next().addClass('checked');
    });

    // add class and checked attribute to filter inputs
    $('.open-checkbox').click(function () {
        console.log('click');
        var $this = $(this);
        var $input = $this.find('input');

        $this.toggleClass('checked', $input.is(':checked'));
        return;

        if($input.prop('checked')){
            $this.removeClass('checked');
        } else {
            $this.addClass('checked');
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you provide us with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

to check the checkbox add:

```
 $input.attr('checked','checked');
```

to uncheck:

```
$input.removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` and `id`s don't match. Change your `id` to "checkbox-insights-and-planning" (was missing an 's') and it should work.

Also make sure your image path is correct (we can't test that with your example code as it's a relative path; I just tried it with a background-color and it worked).

Comment: This was helpful; however, hiding the checkbox with {visibility:hidden;} also hides the image swap...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.  The JS was fine.  The fix was to nest the `inputs` inside of the `label` and wrap inside of a `div.`  This gave the desired effect.